# Regex to match image id from url

Tags: javascript, regex, url

I have a URL as follow:

```
https://res.cloudinary.com/frivillighet-norge/image/upload/v1501681528/5648f10ae4b09f27e34dd22a.jpg
```

and I want to match only the id of the picture at the end of the string without including .jpg. So far, I have written something like that: `^[A-Za-z0-9]{24}$` which matches a string of numbers and letters with a length of 24, since my id in the string has always length 24, but this does not work as it matches strings of length 24 only.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you just want to inject the last part of the URL? Also, is there any specific reason to use regular expression for that?

Comment: Try using a capturing group `https?:\/\/\S+\/([A-Za-z0-9]{24})\.\w+$` https://regex101.com/r/R8V7iS/1

Comment: I actually just need to extract the id from the url.

Comment: @DonaldShahini  The id is in the capturing group. See https://ideone.com/ZlcGH5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make the pattern a bit more specific by matching the protocol followed by matching 1+ occurrences of a non whitespace char `\S+`.

Then match the last occurrence of `/` and capture the id which consists of 24 characters `([A-Za-z0-9]{24})` followed by matching a dot and 2 or more times a char a-z `\.[a-z]{2,}`

If you want to match the whole string, you could add anchors to assert the start `^` and  end `$` of the string.

The id is in capture group 1.

```
^https?:\/\/\S+\/([A-Za-z0-9]{24})\.[a-z]{2,}$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/zcWvhR/1)

```js
const regex = /https?:\/\/\S+\/([A-Za-z0-9]{24})\.\w+$/;
const str = `https://res.cloudinary.com/frivillighet-norge/image/upload/v1501681528/5648f10ae4b09f27e34dd22a.jpg`;

console.log(str.match(regex)[1])
```

Answer (score 2):

```
[A-Za-z0-9]{24}(?=(\.jpg))
```

"(?=(.jpg))" is a [lookaround](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html). It ends the match with .jpg but does not include it.

Comment: I am accepting this as the right answer but a better solution seems to be ```https?:\/\/\S+\/([A-Za-z0-9]{24})\.\w+$``` suggested by @Thefourthbird